# Return Longest Path with nodes of same value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was just studying up on some Google Interview Questions and I stumbled upon this one online that I can't seem to even understand

Consider an undirected tree with N nodes, numbered from 1 to N. Each node has a label associated with it, which is an integer value. Different nodes can have the same label. Write a function that, given a zero indexed array A of length N, where A[j] is the label value of the (j + 1)-th node in the tree and a zero-indexed array E of length K = (N – 1) * 2 in which the edges of the tree are described, returns the length of the longest path such that all the nodes on that path have the same label. The length is the number of edges in that path.

Example:

A = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2]
E = [1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4, 2, 5]

This tree is shown below. A node follows the form label, value.

```
----------1, 1

-----1, 2        1, 3

2, 4      2, 5
```

The function should return 2, because the longest path is 2->1->3, and there are 2 edges in this path.

Assume that 1 <= N <= 1000 and each element of the array A is an integer in the range [1, 1000000000].

**What is your take on breaking this up to solve? Thanks!**

Answer (score 2):

Here is my suggestion. I haven't checked it thoroughly.

```
from collections import defaultdict

A = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2] 

E = [1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4, 2, 5]

d = defaultdict(list)
it = iter(E)
for k, v in zip(it, it):
    d[k].append(v)
    d[v].append(k)

leaves = [k for k, v in d.items() if len(v) == 1]

def len_path(node, length=0, coming_from=None):

    max_loc_len = length
    loc_data = A[node-1]

    available_nodes = {i: A[i-1] for i in d[node]}
    available_nodes.pop(coming_from, None)

    for i, i_data in available_nodes.items():
        cumul = length + 1 if loc_data == i_data else 0
        loc_len = len_path(i, cumul, node)
        if loc_len > max_loc_len:
            max_loc_len = loc_len 

    return max_loc_len

max_len = max([len_path(leaf) for leaf in leaves])
```

And a more sophisticated search, avoiding computing the same path twice:

```
# ...
def len_path(node, length=0, coming_from=None, fork=False):

    max_loc_len = length
    loc_data = A[node-1]

    available_nodes = {i: A[i-1] for i in d[node]}
    available_nodes.pop(coming_from, None)

    matching_nodes = [k for k, v in available_nodes.items()
                         if v == loc_data and k not in leaves[:explored]]
    if len(matching_nodes) > 1:
        fork = True

    if not available_nodes and not fork and node in leaves[explored:]:
        # Reached an unexplored leaf without forks on the path, 
        # hence no need to explore it later
        leaves.remove(node)

    for i, i_data in available_nodes.items():
        cumul = length + 1 if loc_data == i_data else 0
        loc_len = len_path(i, cumul, node, fork)
        if loc_len > max_loc_len:
            max_loc_len = loc_len 

    return max_loc_len

explored = 0
max_len =0

while explored < len(leaves):
    length = len_path(leaves[explored])
    if length > max_len:
        max_len = length
    explored += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach can be like this:

- Build an adjacency list from the input
- Choose a node and find the diameter of the subtree of that node which have the same labels

Maximum diameter will be the answer

Answer (score 0):

Much more simpler approach:

```
import operator

A = [1, 1, 1 ,2, 2]

d = {}
final = {}

def func(node, val):
    if len(A) < node: return 0
    if A[node-1] == val: return 1
    else: return 0

for idx, a in enumerate(A):
    id = idx+1
    d[id] = (a,func(id+id, a),func((id*2)+1 , a))

for val in d.values():
    i1,i2,i3 = val
    if i1 not in final:
        final[i1] = 0
    final[i1] += i2 + i3

print(max(final.iteritems(),key = operator.itemgetter(1))[1])
```